# Rails does not serve some images after replacing them in assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, image, openlayers, asset-pipeline

I currently embed OpenLayers in my Rails 3.2.2 app. OpenLayers' images are in `/vendor/assets/images/openlayers`, and they're correctly served.

In another folder, I've edited some of those images, using Photoshop, to change the hues of the buttons. Now, when I replace the images, Rails won't serve them anymore, instead just showing this "broken image" icon.

Before and after (note that I didn't modify the image that forms the zoombar's background):

[image] [image]

The image is served, according to the rails console:

```
Started GET "/assets//openlayers/zoom-minus-mini.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-15 23:09:04 +0200
Served asset /openlayers/zoom-minus-mini.png - 200 OK (0ms)
```

… but in my browser it just shows the "broken image" icon again, when I browse to that URL. If I drag the image from my file system to Chrome, it shows it correctly.

When I do a `git checkout vendor/assets/images/openlayers` and refresh the browser (skipping the cache), everything's back to normal.

What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that editing the *original* images *in place* fixed the problem, rather than copying them to the destination directory in `vendor/assets/images`.

Even though they were showing fine in Finder, Photoshop, Chrome, Safari, and other tools, Rails refused to serve them for whatever reason.

<sub>If someone has a more technical explanation of why that would happen, feel free to share!</sub>